# Primefaces: DataTable inside AccordionPanel throws NullPointerException

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, accordionpane

I have a Primefaces DataTable inside an AccordionPanel with dynamic number of tabs. The DataTable can be sorted by each column by click on the column header.
The DataTable throws an NullPointerException in Primefaces' DataTable class when updating a row. The error occurs only after the table has been sorted before.
I've tested the same table outside the accordion, and it does not show the error.

What am I doing wrong ?

My xhtml:

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="contentForm">

      <p:accordionPanel id="wearDataAccordion" value="#{wearDataBean.wearDataTypes}" var="type" multiple="true">
        <p:tab title="#{wearDataBean.getAggregateTypeLabel(type)}">

          <p:dataTable width="100%" var="wearData" value="#{wearDataBean.getWearData(type)}" sortBy="#{wearData.aggregate.sequence}" sortOrder="ASCENDING" 
                       scrollable="false" rowStyleClass="" styleClass="" emptyMessage="#{messages['lbl.no.data']}">

            <p:column headerText="#{messages['lbl.weardata.label']}" sortBy="#{wearData.aggregate.sequence}" width="15%">
              <p:outputLabel value="#{wearData.label}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column styleClass="column-numerical-right" headerText="#{messages['lbl.weardata.value']}" 
                                              sortBy="#{wearDataBean.getValue(wearData)}" width="5%">
              <p:outputLabel value="#{wearDataBean.getValue(wearData)}" style="float:right"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{messages['lbl.weardata.unit']}" sortBy="#{wearData.unitId}" width="10%">
              <p:outputLabel value="#{wearDataBean.getUnitLabel(wearData.unitId)}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{messages['lbl.weardata.lastUpdate']}" sortBy="#{wearData.lastUpdate}" width="20%">
              <p:outputLabel value="#{wearData.lastUpdate}">
                <f:convertDateTime dateStyle="medium" timeStyle="medium" type="both" timeZone="#{localeData.timeZoneId}"/>
              </p:outputLabel>
            </p:column>  

            <p:column styleClass="column-button-icon" headerText="#{messages['lbl.dest.actions']}" width="7%">
              <eae:commandButton icon="/resources/images/ui_content_dest_service.svg" styleClass="" svgStyleClass="ui-svg-button-icon-only-svg-size" 
                                                title="#{messages['lbl.weardata.reset']}" action="#{wearDataBean.reset(wearData)}" global="false">
                <p:confirm header="#{messages['lbl.weardata.reset']}" message="#{messages['lbl.weardata.confirm.question']}" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
              </eae:commandButton>
            </p:column>

          </p:dataTable>

        </p:tab>
      </p:accordionPanel>


      <p:remoteCommand name="updateBean" actionListener="#{wearDataBean.updateData()}" global="false"/>
    </h:form>

    <p:socket onMessage="handleWearDataMessage" channel="#{messagePublisher.wearDataUpdateChannelName}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function handleWearDataMessage(data) {
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
        updateBean([{name: 'data', value: jsonString}]);
      }
    </script>

  </ui:define>
```

The exception it throws is:

```
13:20:47,060 [SEVERE] [org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler] (default task-7) null: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.findColumnInGroup(DataTable.java:903) [primefaces-5.1.14.jar:5.1.14]
   at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.findColumn(DataTable.java:894) [primefaces-5.1.14.jar:5.1.14]
   at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getSortColumn(DataTable.java:1401) [primefaces-5.1.14.jar:5.1.14]
   at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.singleSort(SortFeature.java:136) [primefaces-5.1.14.jar:5.1.14]
   at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.preRender(DataTableRenderer.java:109) [primefaces-5.1.14.jar:5.1.14]
   at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:83) [primefaces-5.1.14.jar:5.1.14]
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
   at org.primefaces.component.accordionpanel.AccordionPanelRenderer.encodeTab(AccordionPanelRenderer.java:226) [primefaces-5.1.14.jar:5.1.14]
   at org.primefaces.component.accordionpanel.AccordionPanelRenderer.encodeTabs(AccordionPanelRenderer.java:171) [primefaces-5.1.14.jar:5.1.14]
   at org.primefaces.component.accordionpanel.AccordionPanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(AccordionPanelRenderer.java:103) [primefaces-5.1.14.jar:5.1.14]
   at org.primefaces.component.accordionpanel.AccordionPanelRenderer.encodeEnd(AccordionPanelRenderer.java:76) [primefaces-5.1.14.jar:5.1.14]
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
   at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:582) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
   at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
   at org.primefaces.component.api.UITabPanel.visitTree(UITabPanel.java:948) [primefaces-5.1.14.jar:5.1.14]
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
   at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
   at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
   at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:322) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
   at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60) [primefaces-5.1.14.jar:5.1.14]
   at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
   at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
   at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:430) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
   at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
   at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
   at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
   at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:129) [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
```

The `updateData()` method from the backing bean is as following:

```
 /**
   * Refreshes the data within this bean 
   */
  public void updateData() {
    this.logger.debug("Ajax listener method for wearDataUpdate called!");

    // do update data
    boolean refreshAll = false;
    boolean refresh    = false;
    UpdateEvent<Integer> updateEvent = this.extractRequestData(new TypeToken<UpdateEvent<Integer>>() { /* ignored */ }.getType(), "data");
    if (updateEvent.getType().equals(Type.CREATE)) {
      refresh |= this.addWearDataToDomainData(updateEvent.getData());
    } else if (updateEvent.getType().equals(Type.DELETE)) {
      refresh |= this.removeWearDataFromDomainData(updateEvent.getData());
    } else {
      refreshAll = true;
    }

    // delete old data if refresh all is set
    if (refreshAll) {
      this.wearDataListsByType = null;
    }

    // update table in view
    if (refresh || refreshAll) {
      Ajax.update("contentForm:wearDataAccordion");
    }
  }
```

---

PrimeFaces 5.1.14, Omnifaces 2.0, WildFly 8.2.0

Comment: primefaces-5.1.14.jar != 5.3.4 ???

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry...   we're using 5.1.14.  I've changed it in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `widgetVar="data"` inside datatable.
Is necessary to Javascript recognize this ID.

```
<p:dataTable width="100%" var="wearData" value="#{wearDataBean.getWearData(type)}" sortBy="#{wearData.aggregate.sequence}" sortOrder="ASCENDING" 
                   scrollable="false" rowStyleClass="" styleClass="" emptyMessage="#{messages['lbl.no.data']}" widgetVar="data">
```

[Intro To PrimeFaces widgetVar](http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar/)

Comment: widgetVar != an id...  what does your updateBean do? Only in **that** context, this answer makes sesnse

Comment: id="" can be recognized by the JSF ::
widgetVar="" can be recognized by the Javascript

Comment: An ID can be recognized by JSF but also by the client. The widgetVar is indeed mainly used on the client side by Javascrtipt... BUT... No-where in the original post it is clear that the 'data' value in the call is an id or widgetVar. So adding 'data' as a widgetVar is by no means certain to be the solution. And stating the adding this widgetVar inside the datatable for javascript to recognize this 'id' is either wrong, or at least misleading. There is NO id assigned, so it is dynamic and **not** 'data'

Comment: I have added the `updateData()` method from the backing bean to the question. I hope that helps. `data` contains an `UpdateEvent` object which contains the id of a `WearDataEntity` object in its data field.

Answer (score 1):

I  had the same problem regarding the sorting of datatables dynamically generated in tabs from `accordionPanel` and the `widgetVar` solution didn't fix my issue.

The solution that made the sorting work was to include a `p:columnGroup`(not so useful besides making things work)

```
<p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>
        <p:column headerText="Column 1">...</p:column>
        ...
    </p:row>
</p:columnGroup>
```